# Extjs rowEditing rownumberer, rownumbers are always 0

Tags: extjs, editing, gridpanel, row-number

I use extjs grid panel with rowediting plugin and have rownumberer column on it.

With a button, I add a new row to the top of the grid. In the edit mode, rownumbers are correct. However when I quit edit mode (complete or cancel) all of the rownumbers become 0.

I could not find similar problems around. I tried to refresh grid after adding a new row, but still row numbers are 0.

Could you please help me to find what the problem is?

[image: without editing]

[image: with editing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the renderer function again and now it works well.

```
            {
                xtype: 'rownumberer',
                renderer: function (v, p, record, rowIndex) {
                    if (this.rowspan) {
                        p.cellAttr = 'rowspan="' + this.rowspan + '"';
                    }
                    return rowIndex + 1;
                }
            },
```